# How to sum up numbers in a DataFrame containing mixed numbers and strings

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sum up numbers (integers or floats) in a DataFrame column that contains mixed numbers and strings.

Actually I am new to pandas and I just tried the easy, straightforward way.

Assuming the following:

```
e = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,1))
e[0][1]='x'
e[0][4]='y'
```

Doing
    e[0].sum()

certainly returns a type error.

I suspect to replace the strings with pd.np.nan. But how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sum up all the numeric values in Pandas Data Frame to yield one value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239605/how-to-sum-up-all-the-numeric-values-in-pandas-data-frame-to-yield-one-value)

Comment: not completely the same as it sums up the full DataFrame and not just the slice.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.to_numeric`:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.to_numeric(e[0], 'coerce').sum()
```

Output:

```
-1.8781900945531884
```

- `coerce` option will set any invalid element as `NaN`, and `pd.Series.sum` by default excludes the `NaN`s in its calculation.